# How to get the rows with the smallest value in a list of values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by

I have a data set like this:

```
id       item         value
1         B             6
2         B             1
3         A             1
4         C             3
5         D             6
6         D             9
```

I need to fetch items with specific values, only once with the smallest value, sorted by items.
So if I need only items with the values 1,6 or 3 I would like to get as a response:

```
id       item         value
    3         A             1
    2         B             1
    4         C             3
    5         D             6
```

I have tried using group by with ordering by the value, but it seems like the group takes the first fitting row:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE value IN (1,3,6) GROUP BY item ORDER BY item, value
```

instead of getting row -

```
 2         B          1
```

I get the row -

```
 1         B          6
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `SELECT * ` with `GROUP BY item ORDER BY item, value` ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work:
input:

```
  select max(id),item,min(value) from tbl1 where value in(1,3,6) group by 
  item ;
```

ouput:

```
max(id) item    min(value)
3   A   1
2   B   1
4   C   3
5   D   6
```

Comment: It seems like this is the desirable solution for me, it does the work, though it is a bit risky - I need to activate min/max logic on other fields as well.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `group by` to filter the data.  That is what `where` is for.  In this case, use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tbl1 t1
WHERE t1.value IN (1, 3, 6) AND
      t1.value = (SELECT MIN(tt1.value) FROM tbl1 tt1 WHERE tt1.item = t1.item AND tt1.value IN (1, 3, 6));
```

With reasonable indexes, the above should be fast enough.  Note that the filtering on `value` in the outer query is not needed.

For performance, I would phrase this as:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tbl1 t1
WHERE t1.id = (SELECT tt1.id
               FROM tbl1 tt1
               WHERE tt1.item = t1.item AND
                     tt1.value IN (1, 3, 6)
               ORDER BY tt1.value 
               LIMIT 1
              );
```

This query assumes that `tbl1(id)` is the primary key (seems like a reasonable assumption).  Then you want an index on `tbl1(tt1, item, value, id)`.

Comment: Considering It's a big table - wouldn't it make performance issues?

Answer (score 0):

use corelated subquery

```
select t.* from your_table t where t.value =
( select min(value) from your_table t1 where t1.item=t.item
  and t1.value in (1,3,6)
) and t.value in (1,3,6)
```